# Bazel build NodeJS C++ Addon

Tags: bazel

I've created a sample library with Bazel: `https://github.com/rynz/test-app`

How do I go about building this library in a NodeJS C++ Addon?

Can I build a NodeJS addon with Bazel? Else, what are the steps to include a Bazel library with node-gyp?

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs addons are encapsulated in their own side, you have to do the connections.To work with an addon you need to convert all js arguments to c/c++, so you can work with them.

napi string example:

```
    napi_value argv[1];
    size_t argc = 1;
    char* str[LENGTH];

    napi_get_value_string_utf8(
          env          //environment
        , argv[0]      //napi_value represents a js string
        , (char*) &str //(c/c++)buffer to store the utf8 string
        , sizeof(str)      //dest buffer size
        , &argc     // src buffer size 
    );

    //now you can work with str in c/c++

    //Do your stuff here
```

After the addon work you need to convert the c/c++ return values to js values.

Returning the string:

```
    napi_value result;

    napi_create_string_utf8(
          env
        , (char*) &str     //(c/c++)buffer to convert to napi
        , NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH //buffer size AUTO_LENGTH if its null-terminated
        , &result          //the resulting napi string
    );

    //now you can return result as napi_value
```

Check the complete docs here https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html